# Error while attempting to use TempPath in WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

Im attempting to download a file into the temp folder of an Azure WebJob...

```
 public static string DownloadLogo(string url)
    {
        var fileName = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}logo.png";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\BillingProcessor\t2argeef.l1b\public\logo.png'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\BillingProcessor\t2argeef.l1b\public\logo.png'. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\BillingProcessor\t2argeef.l1b\public\logo.png'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
```

On a separate note:

1. I navigated into D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\BillingProcessor\t2argeef.l1b\  and the public folder is not present
2. I have this same code running other webjob deployments without any issues

Comment: Differences between this deployment and others are:
Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0 vs. Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked fine. But my filename is `D:\local\Temp\logo.png`, it's different from yours.

So i tried to change the path to `{Path.GetTempPath()}t2argeef.l1b/public/logo.png`, then it will show the same error just like yours. So for now i'm sure the problem is the file folder doesn't exist.

The way i solve the problem is go to the **Kudu**  and create the file folder like the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuD6D.png) shows. Then run the **webjob**, it works fine. And this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjijt.png).

And i think your **kudu** environment `TEMP` was changed , this caused your temp file folder directory error. So you could check your `TEMP` environment from `Kudu console` with `set` or from Kudu environment [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Kjj.png).

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know that code works if manually creating the temp folder, Im trying to figure out why it points to that folder.... This is my kudu setting "Temp folder D:\local\Temp\"

Comment: @pmeyer Is TEMP and TMP the same as "D:\local\Temp\"?

Comment: And you could use ""Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");"" to check TMP,TEMP and USERPROFILE ,under normal situation it will return path fisrst ""TMP then "TEMP" the last is "USERPROFILE".